# Adding modules to a google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am follwing documentation to write [a simple trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#functions-deploy-command-python) for my bucket insertion , I am doing this in Python and then deployed the function using gcloud,

my python function is the same as documentation, but I wonder how If i wanna use this function within a project for example I need this function to read the file and publish them to kafka, can I add any external module to this function or using other classes in the python project containing my function?

```
def gcs_object_insert(data, context):
    print('Event ID: {}'.format(context.event_id))
    print('Event type: {}'.format(context.event_type))
    print('Bucket: {}'.format(data['bucket']))
    print('File: {}'.format(data['name']))
    print('Metageneration: {}'.format(data['metageneration']))
    print('Created: {}'.format(data['timeCreated']))
    print('Updated: {}'.format(data['updated']))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime#specifying_dependencies) is clear about how to include dependencies.

> A function is allowed to use other third-party libraries as well as
>   other local data. Dependencies in Python are managed with pip and
>   expressed in a metadata file called `requirements.txt` shipped
>   alongside your function. This file must be in the same directory as
>   the main.py file that contains your function code.